# How to implement custom escape sequence related new line in c# Windows8?

Tags: c#, escaping, windows-8

I am implementing Windows8 C# application in this application using read only mode text box .

i am identifying next line using some custom escape sequence.

how to implement custom escape sequence in c# metro application?

Regards
Narasimha

Comment: What is a "custom escape sequence"?

Comment: suppose i am taking read only mode text box i am inserting characters newline identify purpose (\r) custom escape sequence.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not sure if this answers your question, but the following will allow you to create a line break in a textbox:

```
myTextBox.Text += Environment.NewLine;
```

Or:

```
myTextBox.Text = "This is\nA Multi line\nText Box";
```

Comment: this is Environment. Newline predefined text box property i am define custom char  sequence

Comment: Could you post some code with what you have, and what is happening that you don't want to happen, or what is not happening that you do?